# Can Error 419 (unknown status) be related to something other than CSRF-Token?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I'm not managing to solve a problem related to the mentioned error in my application.

Looking for a solution I only find information about how to handle CSRF-tokens and can find anything else, is it possible that if I get this error it has to be a problem with the token?

I'm sending a post requests with axios, from a vue component to Laravel.

Edit: I didn't add the code because I know there are already a lot of threads talking about this, I was just wandering if anyone has ever got this error in some case other than CSRF-token related issue.

Comment: add code for this problem.

Comment: Are you sending the CSRF-Token with the post request?

Answer (score 0):

set in your axios code request

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

and set cookie

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN',window.Cookies.get('_csrf'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `web` routes to call as API then you would get this error on POST request. Please define the API routes in `api.php` and it will start working.